# User Authentication on Android App

Tags: android, android-authenticator

My company is on Office 365 Enterprise and user authentication is done using Azure services. I am creating an Android app which requires user authentication to use the app. Its a requirement that the user has to be connected virtually to our company network using Cisco VPN. Launching the app is performed only after successfully connected to company domain.

How would I handle authentication? Thanks.

Comment: this is not a wikihow. try to do it yourself. when you face a problem.post it.you will find plenty of people to help.

Comment: @BishoyAbd While there are many ways to handle this task. I was interested to know the best way to perform. But I understand what you are trying to say. I wanted to know 'how to' but not the actual code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) for user authentication and database purposes. Its the most easy,secure and efficient method for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need some very special logic for this.

1. User opens the app
2. App tries to make a web request (which is on the
   vpn).
3. If the user is not connected to the vpn, the request will
   fail, in which case you can show a message like *"Request failed.
   Make sure you are connected to our VPN network"* (or something
   similar).